# Facebook Open graph image does not scale correctly

Tags: facebook-graph-api, sharethis

I have added an open graph image to my site but in the news feed it is not scaled correctly. The image is clipped both at the top and at the bottom. The image itself is a png with the size of 1500x1500px.

Looking at my profile page where the image is placed to the left of the text it scales correctly.

I have specified the following meta tags: og:title, og:type, og:image, og:url, and og:description.

I use the ShareThis API for the actual share button (if that can have anything to do with this).

Has anyone had this problem as well?

Comment: Yep. Same problem here. And I could create the image in the right size for Facebook, but I won't since then it probably wouldn't be right for other services using the og:image.